# Access to an array

Tags: javascript

after a while I need your help again ;-). I found following javascript

```
var global_index = 0;
var db = [ "10000000", "01000000", "00100000", "00010000", "00001000", "00000100", "00000010", "00000001" ];

function loadled()
{
    var byte = db[ global_index ];
    if( global_index < 7 ) global_index++; else global_index = 0;
    for( var x = 0; x < byte.length; x++ )
    {
        document.getElementById("id_" + x ).src = [ "led_off.gif", "led_on.gif" ][ parseInt( byte[ x ], 10 ) ];
    }
    window.setTimeout( loadled, 100 );
}
window.onload = loadled;

</script></head>  
</html>
```

I don't understand following line:

```
document.getElementById("id_" + x ).src = [ "led_off.gif", "led_on.gif" ][ parseInt( byte[ x ], 10 ) ];
```

Can anyone provide a simple explanation for this or a comparison to common writing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("id_" + x ).src = [ "led_off.gif", "led_on.gif" ][ parseInt( byte[ x ], 10 ) ];
```

> document.getElementById("id_" + x)

selects the html element named id_x (where x is the variable in your code)

> .src

specifies that you want to change the source of the html element selected above

> [ "led_off.gif", "led_on.gif" ][
>   parseInt( byte[ x ], 10 ) ];

that will either render to "led_off.gif" or "led_on.gif" depending on the value of x.

`parseInt(byte[x],10)` tries to convert a string to numeral format (and in this case the numeral format based on 10), and will either be 0 or 1.

So the line will become:

> document.getElementById("id_[x]").src
>   = "led_off.gif"

or

> document.getElementById("id_[x]").src
>   = "led_on.gif"

depending on the value of x. Which means that the source of the image with the id=id_x will change source to the other gif.

Comment: The element with id 'id_' + x was cutted off, because I wantet to reduce the source code to a minimum. Ant thanks for your simple explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I belive that the following code : `parseInt( byte[ x ], 10 )` will always return 0 or 1 thus selecting eiter "led_off.gif" or "led_on.gif" as the src of the element x :)

HTH :)

Comment: I thought 'parseInt( byte[ x ], 10 )' returns an decimal number, parsed from a binary one. And even if so, what does mean '[ "led_off.gif", "led_on.gif" ][0]'? Does the second argument specife which element the browser should take?

Comment: parseInt can never return a decimal ... the integer data type does not have float figures! ... yes ["led_off.gif","led_on.gif"] is a short hand way of declaring an array on the fly. Adding the [0] after indicates the selection of the first element in that array.

Comment: Thanks for your last comment. That has improved my understanding in arrays, so you I marked it as great comment.